# Spring @Service generics: Do I need to create a bean for each type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create a generic crud service that I can use for any type of entity. But when I was trying it I noticed that even though I was autowired several different services like

```java
@Autowired
MyService<Item> itemService;

@Autowired
MyService<Students> studentsService;
```

When I tried the .findAll() method I noticed it was returning items.. on both services! So after doing some debugging I noticed that the instances of itemService and studentsService are the same which would explain what I just mentioned.

To make sure of this I made some small test as follows:

```java
    @Autowired
    Foo<String> fooStr;

    @Autowired
    Foo<Long> fooLong;

    static int counter = 0;

    @Service
    class Foo <T> {
        public Foo(){
            counter++;
        }
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
        System.out.println("hello world, I have just started up " + counter);
    }
```

Basically I set up a generic foo service and autowire it under what I assume should be two different instances(Foo and Foo), and a counter on the constructor to check how many times this class is instantiated. However, instead of counter = 2(one from fooStr and another one from fooLong) it's actually 1 which I guess confirms my previous assumption.

So here's my question: Do I actually need to declare a bean myself for each type of generic if I use @Service? Isn't there an easier way? I have to make lots of cruds for a project that are pretty much the same so I'd really like to avoid having to declare all the beans for each entity type if possible

Comment: Read about @Qualifier on spring beans

Comment: Check out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire-generics

Answer (score 1):

By default `Service` is a singleton. In order to get a new instance each time, use
`@Scope("prototype")` annotation on your `Service` class

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to keep it a singleton but make a new instance if it's a different generic type without me having to define a bean for each generic type?